# Building a Document Managament System from Scratch (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, system, document

I'm about to embark on a new Document Management System/Knowledge-base system using ASP.Net and I'm wondering what are the best practices and design issues I need to consider before starting up. I am a learning software engineer and I would like to develop my software engineering skills with this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this as a personal project to learn ASP.Net, I'd suggest using an N-Tier architecture or ASP.Net MVC.

Assuming this is a work project, I'd say: Why re-invent the wheel? Investigate SharePoint or a CMS system to see if they already do what you need.